# <function> is not a member of <class>

Tags: c++, class, methods, compiler-errors, turbo-c++

I have declared my function 'Credit' as a private member with some arguments. My observation is that whenever I try to compile without any argument the compiler will compile successfully. but as soon as I compile with the arguments in the function, the compiler gives an error

> 'Transaction :: Credit' is not a member of 'Transaction'

Here is my code

```
class Transaction : public Menu
{
private :

    void Credit(int depost);//{ return 0;}

public :
    void Deposit();
    void Withdraw(){}
    void Transfer(){}
};

void Transaction :: Deposit()
{
       char custid[10]; int deposit;

       clrscr();
       cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
       cout << "\t\t\t\t  DEPOSIT " << endl;
       cout << "\t\t   Please enter your Customer ID" << endl;
       cin  >> custid;
       cout << "\t\t   Please enter the amount you want to deposit (in Rupees)" << endl;
       cin  >> deposit;

 //      Credit (depost);
}

void Transaction :: Credit (depost)
{

}
```

I am using Turbo C++, so please guide me according this IDE.

Comment: The definition `void Transaction::Credit(depost)` should have a type specifier for `depost` ie
`void Transaction::Credit(int depost)`

Comment: That's it! Thanks. But why do we need a type specifier? @YoungJohn

Comment: @Swanav: Why wouldn't you? C++ is a strong (for the most part anyway...), statically typed language.

Comment: I understand that I'm seeing very little of your code, but I'm going to use my deductive skills and say that deriving a class which does banking transactions from a class called `Menu` is almost certainly a bad design.

Comment: In C, if the type specifier wasn't given, it would default to `int`. C++ removed that default and required it to be specified.  So, depending on whether TurboC++ enforces that restriction, it should have either worked, or been a syntax error.  TC++'s error message is clearly wrong.

Comment: You need to upgrade your ancient compiler; also, do you need to clear the screen?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is a school assignment and the school wants the program in Turbo C++, I don't have much of a choice. And yes, I need to clear my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the type of depost:

```
void Transaction :: Credit (int depost)
```

Comment: Naming function from capital letter is not bad practice. It is just an opinion. Quoting Google Style Sheet [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Function_Names):

"Ordinarily, functions should start with a capital letter and have a capital letter for each new word"

Comment: Downvote because you forced your opinion on naming convention when it's entirely subjective. Remove the last bit and I'll remove my downvote.